# How to get the title tag to display after dynamically changing it

Tags: javascript

I am changing the title tag of a span to display the first line of the discrepancy message that it links to.  Everything is working great except that the message displays onmousover, so the "magic" only happens when the user mouses over the span tag.  The problem is that the title only displays if you move the mouse again, after the initial mouseover that triggers the event.  Is there a way around this?  Is it possible to set the title to call the JavaScript function instead of calling it on mouseover?

```
echo '<td valign="top" align="center">'.(($job['numberOfUnreadMessages'] > 0) ? ' <span class="badge1" id="' . $job['id'] . '"  data-badge="'.$job['numberOfUnreadMessages'].'" onmouseover="showMessage(' . $job['id'] . ', ' . $job['numberOfUnreadMessages'] . ');"></div>' : '&nbsp;' );
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
function showMessage(jobid, numOfUnreadMessages) {
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let jid = jobid;
    request.open('GET', '<?php echo site_url('job/getDiscrepancyByJobId'); ?>/' + jobid, true);
    request.onload = function() {
        if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
            if ((this.response).contains('<div')) {
                document.getElementById(jid).title = numOfUnreadMessages + ' number of unresolved discrepancies.';
            } else {
                 let message = decodeURIComponent(this.response);
                 document.getElementById(jid).title = message;
                 document.getElementById(jid).focus();
            }
        } else {
            // Error
        }
    };
    request.send();
 }
```

Comment: Why does this have to happen “dynamically” and waits until the user hovers over the element? Why is the title not set as it should display right away?

Comment: @04FS, the title is only supposed to display the first line of the message if the user hovers over the span tag (which appears as a number in a small circle).  You raise a good point though. I will try and rethink this.

Comment: Making an AJAX request on every mouseover event is not a good idea to begin with. Without any throttling or debouncing that should not be done at all, IMHO. I’d rather poll for new messages in a regular interval (or use server-side events / websockets in the first place) - which would solve your initial problem for the most part as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to O4FS for the help.

I added a field to the array being pulled into the page that brings in the discrepancy message.  I then simply changed the PHP code to:

```
echo '<td valign="top" align="center">'.(($job['numberOfUnreadMessages'] > 0) ? ' <span class="badge1" id="' . $job['id'] . '"  data-badge="'.$job['numberOfUnreadMessages'].'" title="' . $job['titleMessage'] . '"></div>' : '&nbsp;' );
```